# Spring Log in system

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I'm bulding webApp in Spring, which need log in system and authorization system.

For login I will have route that provides JSON Wep Token. Code of checking user:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void test (@RequestBody user checkUser) {

    System.out.println(checkCredentials(checkUser));

}

public final Boolean checkCredentials (user checkUser) {

    try {

        user existingUser = uRepo.getOne(checkUser.getuEmail());
        Boolean match = BCrypt.checkpw(checkUser.getuPassword(),existingUser.getuPassword());
        return match;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("User does not exist!");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

For now its raw, but it checks if there is uses with that email, than will check password.

First question: Is it valid way of checking users credentials? Or should I use spring security?

Secound question: How should I move function to other class? Because when i just moved it and used, I had problems with exceptions (null pointer) and function didn't work.

Third question: is there any good way to make "middleware" like in Node.js? I think it will need to be some kind of HttpRequest Filter but I'm not quite sure. I want to check if user have bearer token to go with other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not best way to do that. Use Spring Security and sit back. Everything you want is bundled in Spring Security. Filters, method level security, roles, authorities...

You can find Spring Security + JWT example projects on Github:

[Here is minimal example](https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-security-jwt)

[More advanced one](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo)

Comment: Thanks! I did it as you said. Using pure spring security. I struggled a little bit but its working.